# Селектор для Label for Input'а с определенным значением

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется группа радиокнопок (с одним именем, но разными значениями в value="")

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
   <input class="custom-control-input " type="radio" name="exampleRadios1" id="exampleRadios1_1" value="a">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleRadios1_1">am</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
     <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios1" id="exampleRadios1_2" value="b">
     <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleRadios1_2">be</label>
 </div>
 <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios1" id="exampleRadios1_3" value="c" >
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleRadios1_3">are</label>
 </div>
 <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios1" id="exampleRadios1_4" value="d" >
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleRadios1_4">is</label>
 </div>
```

скрипт по клику на label присваивает клас .valid "правильному" варианту, .invalid трем остальным label'ам
Вот сам скрипт

```
var result = 0;
$("input[name='exampleRadios1']").on('click', function () {$("input[name='exampleRadios1']").attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('invalid');
$("label").addClass('invalid');
if ($('input[name=exampleRadios1]:checked').val() == 'd') {
    result = result + 1;
    $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}
});
```

В моем скрипте .invalid присваивается ВСЕМ Label`ам, и только если выбран тот, у которого радиокнопка с val() == 'd', тогда ему присваивается .valid .
Мне нужно написать селектор, который присвоит .valid "правильному" label независимо по какому из них был клик.

Comment: Сперва нужно понять как будет определяться "правильность".

Comment: В даном случае в if ($('input[name=exampleRadios1]:checked').val() == 'd')

Comment: Тогда в данном случае все работает.

Comment: Нет, если выбрать вариант не 'd', все лейблы будут с классом invalid, а нужно чтобы 'd' имел valid. 
Вот живой пример http://d.zsayti.com/placement-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение:

```
$('input[name="exampleRadios1"]').change(function(){
    $('label').addClass('invalid');
    $('input[value="d"]').parent().find('label').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
});
```

Но если делать по хорошему, то я бы внутри change() сделал бы проверку всех input через each() и там бы уже проверял их значения:

```
$('input[name="exampleRadios1"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="exampleRadios1"]').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == 'd' ) {
        $(this).parent().find('label').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('label').addClass('invalid');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Идею понял. Сделал по первому варианту, но с небольшой правкой:


           $('input[name="exampleRadios1"][value="d"]').parent().find('label').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');


т.е. дополнительно проверяю name